# Retrieving Specific Data From JSON Using a Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am creating a client view of an application and I need help with retrieving specific data from my JSON file. I am using Backbone.js along with Underscore.js to achieve this.

```
(function($) {

      window.Node = Backbone.Model.extend({
         getName:    function(){
             return this.get('Name');
         } 
     });

      window.Nodes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
         model:Node,
          url: '/packageview.json'
    });

  window.NodeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    className: "package-template",

    events:{

      "click #display-name"       :    "displayname",         
    },

    //.. I have a render and initialize function here which should not be a concern


    displayname: function(){
      var node = new Node();
      alert(node.getName());  //trying to alert
    },

  });
});
```

I am trying to get the name from model and alert it. I have a button in my html with an id, and when I press that button I get "undefined" as an alert. Here is how my JSON file looks:

```
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Some Package",
  "IsComplete": false,
  "IsNodeTagComplete": false
}
```

I think I am making a silly mistake somewhere. Am I expecting way to much from model?

Comment: It's really hard to figure out the problem without seeing other parts of your code. I know this works simply but you have a lot of external dependencies to help us debug. Could you either simplify the above or add concerned HTML/Backbone code? E.g. the Package View node or what is it that is being clicked or where is `nodeinstance` defined?

Comment: Quick question though: why not directly go with `model.get('Name')`? instead of having an explicit getter? Just curious. As for your JSON file, you are NOT creating the model WITH the data...just an empty model. You are bound to get undefined...

Comment: @Nupul: I think I should remove the render and initialize function. Maybe that will simplify the code and can be understood in a better way.

Comment: @Nupul: Well it is not working either. The application of it is really complex. I need to understand how getters and setters will work because I will be using them a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What I am doing here is this

```
 window.jsonAccess = Node.extend({ // Here Node is my above mentioned model

    getJSON: function(){
        var collection = nodeInstance.toJSON(); // nodeInstance is an instance of my collection Nodes
        return collection; //returns JSON
    }
});
jAccess = new jsonAccess();
```

So here is what I am doing to access the JSON

```
 getNodeId: function(){ //Function to get Node Id from JSON
        objectJSON = jAccess.getJSON(); // Get JSON 
        _.each(objectJSON, function(action){
            _.each(action.Nodes, function(action){
```

This solves my purpose but not quite the way getters would be used in backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Since a lot of context is missing I too may be making a mistake but here's my guess - you are creating an empty Node Model. Try doing something like this in display:

```
displayName: function() {

   var myJSON = window.getJSONObject(); //wherever your json object is or how to get it...
   var node = new Node({
   id:myJSON.Id,
   name:myJSON.Name,
   isComplete: myJSON.IsComplete,
   ...
   });

   alert(node.get('name'));
   alert("Getter: "+node.getName()); //your version...
}
```

This is just a hunch though...maybe I'm missing your context but this seems to be the case for now...

Comment: @Nupul.. I found another way around.. Not exactly using getters here.

Comment: @Eric: You should not leave a question dangling. If you did find another way around it'd be great for people stumbling upon this post to know it :)

Comment: I know but the way I am doing it is no where concerned to the question I asked. I still did not figure out using getters in my situation, so the question is unsolved.

Comment: Err...did you look at the fiddle example and the fact I am able to have getters working?? Could you please tell us what is unsolved? Backbone is inbuilt with getters/setter and you don't need to have your own. You can directly use `model.get('propertyName')` or `model.set({prop1:val1, prop2:val2,...})` What is it that is still not working? We should be able to solve the problem :)